# Считать json с файла и изменять, добавлять

Tags: java, json, файлы

есть такой json, он находиться в файле settings.json

```
{
"settings" : {
    "pathDownloads" : "",
    "pathFolder" : {
        "archive" : "",
        "music" : "",
        "android" : "",
        "web" : "",
        "images" : ""
    }
}
}
```

Нужно его прочитать в jsonObject, ну а там изменять добавлять новое и 
записать измененный json обратно в файл.
Проблема сама : прочитать и запись json файл
пересмотрел много примеров, м.б. есть какая-то библиотека ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Стандаpтная библиотека org.json](http://code.google.com/p/org-json-java/downloads/detail?name=org.json-20120521.jar&can=2&q=)

[JSON.simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/detail?name=json-simple-1.1.1.jar&can=2&q=)

GSON

[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        object.put("name", "mkyong.com");
        object.put("age", new Integer(100));

        JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
        list.add("msg 1");
        list.add("msg 2");
        list.add("msg 3");

        object.put("messages", list);

        try{
            FileWriter file = new FileWriter("test.json");
            file.write(object.toJSONString());
            file.flush();
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


        //============================================

        // остановить перед чтением файла
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("test.json"));

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

            String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
            System.out.println(name);

            long age = (Long) jsonObject.get("age");
            System.out.println(age);

            // loop array
            JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("messages");
            Iterator<String> iterator = msg.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ответ вроде нормальный, восстановил.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.